# Optimize switch case angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following function in my anguar controller, there is a lot of repeatation in switch case, I am not sure how can I optimize it?

```
  $scope.start = function() {

       var when;

      console.log("Start: " + $scope.level + " " + $scope.round)
      switch($scope.level + "|"+  $scope.round){
        case "1|1": 
        $scope.promptRound='Level 1 Round 1';
        when=3000
        break;
        case "1|2": 
        $scope.promptRound='Level 1 Round 2';
        when=3000
        break;
        ...  
        case "2|1": 
        $scope.promptRound='Level 2 Round 1';
        when=3000
        break;
        case "2|2": 
        $scope.promptRound='Level 2 Round 2';
        when=3000
        break;
        ...
        default:
        $scope.promptRound='Default';
      }
```

The cases goes on till `case "6|8"` Essentially there are several levels identified by $scope.level and each level has several rounds (each level has different number of rounds) identified by $scope.round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this instead switch?

```
$scope.promptRound = $scope.level && $scope.round 
  ? ['Level', $scope.level, 'Round', $scope.round].join(' ')
  : 'Default';

var when = $scope.level && $scope.round ? 3000 : null;
```

or

```
if($scope.level && $scope.round) {
  var when = 3000;
  $scope.promptRound = ['Level', $scope.level, 'Round', $scope.round].join(' ');
} else {
  $scope.promptRound = 'Default'; 
}
```

Comment: Ah var 'when' has different values for few cases i.e. 3rd round onward its set to 5000 for each level. I didn't post the entire code to avoid repeatation and keep it compact. How can that be handled.

Comment: I fixed it as well! Thanks, this code works perfect.